# each projection in $K$ is finite

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The proof is from Rordam' s book.

If $F$ is a projection in $K$, where $K$ is the $C^*$- algebra of all compact operators on a separable infinite dimensional Hilber space.

Suppose $F$ is infinite, then $F\sim F_0<F$,which implies that $Tr(F-F_0)=0,$ and this entails $F=F_0$.

I don't understand the last step. If $Tr(F-F_0)=0$,we only have $[F]_0=[F_0]_0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question per se, since I am unsure what you mean by the trace on the compacts, but here is a proof  that the compacts are finite that I've concocted.

The argument given by yourself and completed by @Epsilon works whenever there is a faithful trace - for example, UHF algebras are finite by this argument.

As mentioned, the compacts have a densely defined trace (I was being pretty dense myself earlier). Since projections in $\mathbb{K}$ are finite rank, the trace argument works (this essentially boils down to the case of proving that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is finite).

Now to this specific case.

Suppose that $p \sim q < p$ in $\mathbb{K} = \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is separable and infinite dimensional. It is clear that $q < p$ means that $q(\mathcal{H}) \subseteq p(\mathcal{H})$, so that $q(\mathcal{H})$ is a subspace of $p(\mathcal{H})$. What do we know about compact projections? Well the image of the closed unit ball is compact, which is true if and only if the image of said projection is finite dimensional. Thus $p(\mathcal{H})$ and $q(\mathcal{H})$ are finite-dimensional, and if we can show that they have the same dimension, then $p(\mathcal{H}) = q(\mathcal{H})$ and hence $p = q$ (why?).

Now Murray von-Neumann equivalence of projections in $\mathbb{K} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ implies that the range of the projections have the same dimension (why?), so it follows that $p(\mathcal{H}) = q(\mathcal{H})$ since $p \sim q$. Now this implies $p = q$, which contradicts the fact that $q < p$.

Comment: There is an canonical (densely defined) unbounded trace on the compats, defined by $Tr(p) = 1$, where $p$ is a rank one projection.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The trace argument works since the projections are necessarily finite rank. I just mentioned the non-existence of an actual trace since its good to be careful about these things. I'll edit the post to incorporate this.

Answer (score 1):

The trace on $K$ is faithful (since $K$ is simple) and $F-F_0$ is positive. Note that this is nothing special about the compacts.

Comment: You mean we can associate a representation $(\pi_{Tr},H_{Tr})$ of $K$.Since $K$ is simple,then $ker(\pi_{Tr})=0$?

Comment: You could prove that the trace kernel is an ideal, i.e. the set $\{x \in K : Tr(x^*x) = 0 \}$. Another way to see that $Tr$ is faithful, is to use spectral decomposition.

Comment: How to use the spectral decomposition to prove Tr is faithful?

Comment: A positive compact operator can be written as $\sum_i \lambda_i e_i$ where $e_i$ is some basis. Then the trace is simply the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Sorry, $e_i$ should be replcaed by the projection onto the span of $e_i$, i.e. $\lvert e_i \rangle \langle e_i \rvert$.